# 2012 Ninja 250 Clicks When Trying To Start

Tags: motorcycle, starter

tried searching all over the Web to solve this problem without luck!

My 2012 Ninja 250 keeps making a clicking noise coming from under the seat when I press the starter switch.  I have a brand new battery, new spark plugs, fresh gas, and clean oil in the bike.

I took the seat off and the noise is coming from a round part that is mounted under the gas tank almost.(I have no clue what this part is... Maybe the starter solenoid????)
[image: picture of clicking part]

I have little experience working on bikes, but would love to fix this myself if possible. Any idea if replacing this part will fix the issue? What could be some other causes?

Comment: Even though the battery is new, is it fully charged?  You can get your solenoid clicking like that if the battery is low.

Comment: @DucatiKiller the battery has full charge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be the main starter relay. It can very well be the issue to your problem. A relay provides a way to get a higher amperage circuit through to things like the starter solenoid without having all that amperage go through the starter switch itself. I would bet replacing this part would fix your issue. You can try giving it a good rap with the butt of a screwdriver on the silver portion. This may temporarily fix it and allow you to get it started.

Comment: You may want to include removing the battery wires when he replaces it.  Changing a 'hot' solenoid can get exciting the first time you arc it trying to replace if it's never happened to you before   :-)